# Nested objects in JSON response

Tags: json, swagger

I am defining my swagger file as below:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "PSD2 Account  API Specification",
    "description": "PSD2 Account Swagger API Specification",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "basicAuth": {
      "type": "basic"
    }
  },
  "security": [
    {
      "basicAuth": []
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/accounts/{id}/transactionhistory": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Get transaction history",
        "operationId": "GetTransactionHistory",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "fromDate",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "toDate",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date"
          },
          {
            "name": "sumOrDetail",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "noOfEntries",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "toTime",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/200TransactionHistory"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "200TransactionHistory": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "amount": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 25
        },
        "txnCodeDesc": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "accountDesc": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "txnCurrency": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 3
        },
        "accountIBAN": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "valueDate": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "transactionCode": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "code": {
              "type": "string",
              "maxLength": 3
            },
            "subcode": {
              "type": "string",
              "maxLength": 3
            }
          }
        },
        "executionEndTime": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "stmtEntryId": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 90
        },
        "accountId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "transReference": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 60
        },
        "exchangeRate": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 11
        },
        "remittanceInformation": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 65
        },
        "payeeCustomer": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "closeBalance": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "bookingDate": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "currency": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 3
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "txnCurrencyAmount": {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 25
        },
        "payeeAccount": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "openBalance": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is a simple GET request and I want in the response to have the following format:

```
"transactionCode": {
          "code": "thisIsTheCode",
          "SubsubCode": "thisIsTheSubCode"
        }
```

As you can see in the response definition this is how I nest my objects:

```
"transactionCode": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "code": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 3
    },
    "subcode": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 3
    }
  }
}
```

When I am testing my request from Postman, I am getting the following error message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: {"header":{"audit":{"T24_time":107,"parse_time":0},"page_start":0,"page_token":"5fc34084-2496-41f0-a968-084b3b519c88","total_size":0,"page_size":50},"body":}; line: 1, column: 158]
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong? Is this something wrong in the way I am nesting the objects in the response?

Comment: The problem seems to be either with the request data or with the API server. 1) How is the request configured, how does the raw HTTP request data look like? 2) Is the server yours or a third party's? If it's your server, please post the controller code that handles the request.